# Is there any wiki to list open datasets?

Tags: discussion

I think that in future many people will ask for list of open datasets: by country, by argument (science, geography, art,..).  Is a good idea create wiki like these? I think that this wiki could be used also to add new open datasets that you heard of. Or should we start from a question like: "Is there any dataset for Italy?" and convert it later to wiki?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure creating a catch-all wiki for this type of misinformation is going to be good for this site.

Remember, the lifeblood of this site is search; Google Search — and if someone is searching for a "Database of politicians for Italy," I sure would like them to find *this* site.

In the bigger picture, this site is supposed to be about answering **specific questions** you encounter in your day to day work. This site *isn't* supposed to be a list of where to find things on the Internet. If you distilled this subject down to a few generic, catch-all lists of where to find stuff, I'm afraid you would miss out on a lot of fascinating problems people are trying to solve.

I would stick to specific questions. Let Open Data SE become a huge repository of fantastically-detailed, long-tailed questions that would serve to separate you from any ol' generic site on the subject. That's how we're going to hold the interest of the *experts* you are trying attract.

Comment: Surely the spirit of this site is, like others SE sites, a knowledge base of Q&A. What think is that many questions will be "where can I find X?" and will become FAQs creating "noise" between specific questions. This is why I'm asking if it's useful having a (single) wiki to summarize this kind of answers.

Comment: I agree that I don't think a wikipage on this site is a good thing. I would rather have a lot of "I'm looking for X" questions that we can answer, vote on, timestamp and administer than create a single page that gains none of the benefits of the content-model of StackExchange websites.

Answer (score 3):

I like this idea, but maintaining such a list might be problematic and as others point out, it's a better idea to empower search engines like Google to find those datasets.

There is a new dataset type added to Schema.org and built on the W3C's DCAT work described at http://schema.org/Dataset  The use of this is likely to provide better generic search to actual datasets.  A detailed description behind this is at http://www.w3.org/wiki/WebSchemas/Datasets

There is a listing of government open data sites at http://www.data.gov/opendatasites

(Disclaimer: I serve as the Evangelist for Data.gov)